# Understanding action & observation spaces in gym for custom environments and agents

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, keras-rl

I am currently trying to learn about reinforcement learning (RL). I am quite new to the field, and I apologize for the wall of text.

I have encountered many examples of RL using TensorFlow, Keras, Keras-rl, stable-baselines3, PyTorch, gym, etc. However, I have discovered an oddity in the example codes that I do not understand, and I need some guidance.

The oddity is in the use of gym’s observation spaces. In many examples, the custom environment includes initializing a gym observation space. However, this observation space seems never actually to be used. The environment state is many times created as a secondary variable. This variable is then changed based on the action, and then rewards are calculated.

**My questions:**

Why do we define the observation space if we do not use it? Furthermore, we cannot change the observation space. We cannot say `observation_space[i] = 1`, for example. Is it strictly necessary to have the gym’s observation space? Is it used in the inheritance of the gym’s environment?

The same goes for the action space. Is it strictly necessary to use the gym’s spaces, or can you just use e.g., an `array = [0,1,2]`?

A lot of work has gone into creating spaces such as Discrete, Box, MultiDiscrete etc. and I encounter them repeatedly in tutorials, so they must have a function. I have tried looking at the documentation and other resources online; however, I struggle to find the information I am lacking.

**An example:**

The examples often use a custom agent and custom network with a given environment (CartPole) or create a custom environment using an already built-in function like A2C, A3C, or PPO. It is therefore difficult to find examples that have both sides of the RL framework.

I have the following code from an example YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD6V3rcr_54. The example code regulates the temperature of a shower allowing the agent to learn whether the temperature should go up or down. In the environment, the observation space is created as a Box. However, the state is handled without ever using the observation space. As the agent interacts with the environment, I cannot see where the observation space changes. Generating actions is done using the neural network; however, it uses the state, not the observation space. The state is changed using the state variable, not the observation space. The same is a problem for the action space. They just seem to exist. They seem only to be used to specify input and output shapes for the Neural network.

```
import numpy as np
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
import random
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory


class ShowerEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([25]), high=np.array([50]))
        self.state = 38 + random.randint(-3, 3)
        self.shower_length = 60

    def step(self, action):
        self.state += action - 1
        self.shower_length -= 1

        if self.state >= 37 and self.state <= 39:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = -1

        if self.shower_length <= 0:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False

        self.state += random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1)

        info = {}

        return self.state, reward, done, info

    def render(self):
        pass

    def reset(self):
        self.state = 38 + random.randint(-3, 3)
        self.shower_length = 60
        return self.state


def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=states))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model


def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=100,
                   target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup an environment
    env = ShowerEnv()
    states = env.observation_space.shape
    actions = env.action_space.n

    # build DQN model
    model = build_model(states, actions)
    dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
    dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=["mae"])
    dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=150000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

    # test model
    scores = dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=100, visualize=False)
    print(np.mean(scores.history["episode_reward"]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The majority of the problems you see are demos and simple RL applications, where state space = observation space. They are used synonymously which is not really bad habit. In very few cases at the start you find the observation space being different from the state space, however, as problems get more realistic and grounded you find the difference and the need for both.
2. Don't use a regular array for your action space as discrete as it might seem, stick to the gym standard, which is why it is a standard. Gym tries to standardize RL so as you progress you can simply fit your environments and problems to different RL algos.

**Building new environments every time is not really ideal, it's scutwork. Sticking to the gym standard will save you tonnes of repetitive work.**

Comment: Fair enough. I did not know there was an actual difference between observation and state space. I have since found a post on stack exchange that talks about it. I agree that having a standard is good; however, it can confuse new people to the subject. (Link to the stack exchange post: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5970/what-is-the-difference-between-an-observation-and-a-state-in-reinforcement-learn)

Comment: Yeah at first. It really doesn't make all that sense but higher up you really appreciate it. Imagine focusing on understanding algorithms while also constantly having to create new environments, and custom objects for each novel problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest map, FrozenLake, status = observation space, which is the position of the person.

The observation spaces for CartPole games is given by gym:
https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/classic_control/cart_pole/

In atari games, there is a gap, atari games are pure pixel input(observation spaces), it is like a real person playing the game without knowing the in-game parameters(CartPole games).

I am also new to reinforcement learning, just with the current understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason why we have to define that is stated [here](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/spaces/#the-base-class):

> Spaces are crucially used in Gym to define the format of valid actions and observations. They serve various purposes:
>
> 1. They clearly define how to interact with environments, i.e. they specify what actions need to look like and what observations will look like
> 2. They allow us to work with highly structured data (e.g. in the form of elements of Dict spaces) and painlessly transform them into flat arrays that can be used in learning code
> 3. They provide a method to sample random elements. This is especially useful for exploration and debugging.

For instance, for the Dict space as stated [here](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/spaces/composite/#dict):

> It can be convenient to use Dict spaces if you want to make complex observations or actions more human-readable. Usually, it will not be possible to use elements of this space directly in learning code. However, **you can easily convert Dict observations to flat arrays by using a gymnasium.wrappers.FlattenObservation wrapper.** Similar wrappers can be implemented to deal with Dict actions.

I'm also a green hand in the RL field as well. To be honest, it doesn't completely answer my question. But I hope it sheds some light on it.